# Apps seem running on the Dock, but not on the App switcher

Tags: dock, application-switcher

Some apps are always running on Mac and I can see them on Dock. (For example, iTunes, Evernote, etc.)

I've set the option 'reopen windows when logging back in', so the apps automatically runs again when I turned on or reboot my MacBook Air.

I can see them highlighted with blue indicator on the Dock. When I press Command+Tab to switch between apps, however, I can't see them in the App switcher.

I think the App switcher misbehaving not the Dock. Because the apps are apparently running when look into the Activity monitor.

Is there any way to fix it?